# IndexOutOfRangeException en bucle for con contenido en lista suficiente

Tags: c#, windows, eventos, excepciones, servicio

Tengo actualmente un proyecto que comprueba cada cierto tiempo (a base de Timer y un Interval de 10000 milisegundos) los eventos que hay en el Visor de Eventos y los filtra según ciertas condiciones.
Cada vez que el Timer hace Tick (es decir, que pasa el intervalo de 10 segundos), se obtiene la fecha y hora correspondiente a 10 segundos antes (debido al intervalo) del momento en el que se comprueba y se ejecuta el siguiente método:

```
    // Método que devuelve los eventos de interes de un EventLogEntryCollection que se crearon después de un momento
    private List<EventLogEntry> ultimosEventos(EventLogEntryCollection listaEventos, DateTime momentoMinimo)
    {
        // Lista de eventos de interés
        // 4624: Inicio de Sesión
        // 4634: Cierre de Sesión
        long[] eventos = new long[] { 4624, 4634 };

        // Tabla a devolver con los eventos válidos
        List<EventLogEntry> listaEventosFiltrados = new List<EventLogEntry>();

        // Comprobamos si hay eventos a filtrar
        if (listaEventos.Count > 0)
        {
            // Hay eventos a filtrar
            // Recorremos los eventos que hay que filtrar
            for (int i = 0; i < listaEventos.Count; i++)
            {
                // Obtenemos el evento actual
                EventLogEntry evento = listaEventos[i];     // Línea con excepción

                // Comprobamos si el evento actual sucedió en el último intervalo
                if (evento.TimeGenerated >= momentoMinimo)
                {
                    // El evento es válido respecto a tiempo
                    // Comprobamos si el ID del evento está entre las IDs requeridas
                    if (eventos.Contains(evento.InstanceId))
                    {
                        // El evento tiene una ID válida
                        // Añadimos el evento a la lista
                        listaEventosFiltrados.Add(evento);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Devolvemos la lista obtenida
        return listaEventosFiltrados;
    }
```

Dicho evento obtiene la lista de todos los eventos del visor de eventos (obtenidos mediante EventLog.Entries) y la fecha y hora a partir del que debió generarse un evento para poder añadirse a la lista de eventos filtrados (es decir, que un evento tuvo que generarse hace 10 segundos para poder ser 'aceptado').
Sin embargo, mientras itero listaEventos, me genera un OutOfRangeException siendo la i en la primera prueba alrededor de 28000 y en la segunda 43, y la propiedad Count alrededor de 31000 en ambas pruebas.
¿Alguien que sepa explicar por qué se debe?

Adjunto captura de datos de la excepción:
[image: Captura de datos del IndexOutOfRangeException]

Comment: Puedes especificar en que linea te salta la excepción?

Comment: @Pikoh En la línea de EventLogEntry evento = listaEventos[i];

Comment: Si llamas al proceso solo una vez, en lugar desde un evento tick del timer desde otra parte del código, funciona correctamente? Porque yo no aprecio ningun problema a priori en tu código

Comment: Desconozco, voy a probar

Comment: Al final era que, al ser un EventLogEntryArray dinámico o algo por el estilo, el contenido del mismo varía, y aunque al inicio la longitud fuera una en concreto, en mitad del bucle cambiaba y, como el programa pensaba que había más elementos (debido a los que había inicialmente) daba dicha excepción. Fue solucionado copiando el contenido previamente en otra variable mediante un foreach, así que si pones tu comentario como respuesta valdría igual, y te lo podría marcar como válido

Comment: Si Carlos, eso me temía y por eso te sugerí hacer una copia de la colección. Lo pongo como respuesta por si a alguien en el futuro le puede servir. Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu colección `listaEventos` probablemente esté siendo modificada externamente a tu método. Lo que puedes hacer es copiar la colección al inicio de tal manera que puedas recorrerla sin que sea modificada. Algo similar a lo siguiente, primero haces una copia de la colección:

```
EventLogEntry[] myEventLogEntryArray = new EventLogEntry[myEventLogEntryCollection.Count];
myEventLogEntryCollection.CopyTo(listaEventos, 0);
```

y posteriormente puedes recorrer la copia:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myEventLogEntryArray .Count; i++)
{
     // Obtenemos el evento actual
     EventLogEntry evento = myEventLogEntryArray[i]; ..
```